# how to use AWS services from outside

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We can leverage AWS services from within AWS infrastructure using the ACCESS_ID/ACCESS_SECRET or by assigning the IAM role.

What if I want to access the services from an instance outside of AWS. ex. DigitalOcean. I know that using the ACCESS_Key is not a good option. What is the recommended practice as an alternative to assigning the roles to EC2 instances

Comment: What do you mean by "is not a good option"?

Comment: hard coding access_key in the instance is not right. Ideally the service to service communication should happen through Roles.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein What is the recommended practice as an alternative to assigning the roles to EC2 instances

Comment: I have updated my answer to reference IAM Roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS announced a new feature AWS IAM Anywhere that should help if you need to avoid using access/secret keys.

> AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) now enables workloads that
> run outside of AWS to access AWS resources using IAM Roles Anywhere.
> IAM Roles Anywhere allows your workloads such as servers, containers,
> and applications to use X.509 digital certificates to obtain temporary
> AWS credentials and use the same IAM roles and policies that you have
> configured for your AWS workloads to access AWS resources.

and more here:

> create a trust anchor where you either reference your AWS
> Certificate Manager Private Certificate Authority (ACM Private CA) or
> register your own certificate authorities (CAs) with IAM Roles
> Anywhere. By adding one or more roles to a profile and enabling IAM
> Roles Anywhere to assume these roles, your applications can now use
> the client certificate issued by your CAs to make secure requests to
> AWS and get temporary credentials to access the AWS environment.

AWS Announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/07/aws-identity-access-management-iam-roles-anywhere-workloads-outside-aws/

User Guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rolesanywhere/latest/userguide/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

API calls to AWS go to public endpoints on the Internet. Therefore, they are accessible from *anywhere* on the Internet, not just within AWS.

Therefore, you should use the same method for connecting to AWS both inside AWS and outside AWS.

Using the Access Key and Secret Key as credentials is the correct method.

To **assume an IAM Role**, you must have an initial set of AWS credentials, so that AWS can confirm that you are entitled to assume the role. For example, an IAM User can provide their credentials to assume an IAM Role.

You can also **assign an IAM Role to an Amazon EC2 instance**. In this situation, the AWS service will automatically assume the role on behalf of the instance, and will provide the resulting credentials through the [EC2 instance metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).

If you are using your own computer (not an Amazon EC2 instance), it is not possible to assign an IAM Role. Instead, use an Access Key + Secret Key. They should be stored in your `~/.aws/credentials` file via the AWS CLI `aws configure` command. Never put actual credentials in your code files, since this can be a security risk (eg having credentials stored in GitHub).

Comment: I did not mean accessing the API, I meant alternative to assigning the roles to EC2 instances